# Sabre HotelList not returning total of stay, returns min/max price of first night

Tags: sabre

With the following request to OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ it returns a minimum and maximum for the first night of a guest stay, across all rate codes. Is there a way to get total costs of stays from OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ or an average low and high of stays?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OTA_HotelAvailRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ReturnHostCommand="true" TimeStamp="2015-03-12T02:00:26-06:00" Version="2.1.0">
   <AvailRequestSegment>
      <GuestCounts Count="2" />
      <HotelSearchCriteria NumProperties="100">
         <Criterion>
            <HotelRef HotelCode="0087974" />
         </Criterion>
      </HotelSearchCriteria>
      <RatePlanCandidates>
         <RateRange CurrencyCode="USD" />
      </RatePlanCandidates>
      <TimeSpan Start="03-31" End="04-02" />
   </AvailRequestSegment>
</OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
```

Response in JSON format:

```
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "RPH": "009"
            },
            "BasicPropertyInfo": {
                "@attributes": {
                    "AreaID": "000",
                    "ChainCode": "DN",
                    "Distance": "M",
                    "GEO_ConfidenceLevel": "1",
                    "HotelCityCode": "SLC",
                    "HotelCode": "0087974",
                    "HotelName": "NEWPARK RESORT",
                    "Latitude": "40.721913",
                    "Longitude": "-111.539077"
                },
                "Address": {
                    "AddressLine": [
                        "1456 NEWPARK BOULEVARD",
                        "PARK CITY UT 84098",
                        "2016 TRIPADVR EXCELLENCE AWARD"
                    ]
                },
                "ContactNumbers": {
                    "ContactNumber": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Fax": "1-435-6157767",
                            "Phone": "1-435-6493600"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "DirectConnect": {
                    "Alt_Avail": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "DC_AvailParticipant": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "DC_SellParticipant": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "RatesExceedMax": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "UnAvail": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "LocationDescription": {
                    "Text": "PARK CITY UT"
                },
                "PropertyOptionInfo": {
                    "ADA_Accessible": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "AdultsOnly": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "BeachFront": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "Breakfast": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "BusinessCenter": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "BusinessReady": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "Conventions": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "Dataport": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "Dining": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "DryClean": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "EcoCertified": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "ExecutiveFloors": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "FitnessCenter": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "FreeLocalCalls": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "FreeParking": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "FreeShuttle": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "FreeWifiInMeetingRooms": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "FreeWifiInPublicSpaces": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "FreeWifiInRooms": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "FullServiceSpa": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "GameFacilities": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "Golf": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "HighSpeedInternet": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "HypoallergenicRooms": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "IndoorPool": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "InRoomCoffeeTea": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "InRoomMiniBar": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "InRoomRefrigerator": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "InRoomSafe": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "InteriorDoorways": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "Jacuzzi": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "KidsFacilities": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "KitchenFacilities": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "MealService": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "MeetingFacilities": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "NoAdultTV": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "NonSmoking": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "OutdoorPool": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "Pets": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "Pool": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "PublicTransportationAdjacent": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "RateAssured": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "Recreation": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "RestrictedRoomAccess": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "RoomService": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "RoomService24Hours": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "RoomsWithBalcony": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "SkiInOutProperty": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "SmokeFree": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "SmokingRoomsAvail": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "Tennis": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "WaterPurificationSystem": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "Wheelchair": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "Ind": "true"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "RateRange": {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                        "Max": "450.00",
                        "Min": "200.00"
                    }
                },
                "RoomRate": {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "RateLevelCode": "RAC"
                    },
                    "AdditionalInfo": {
                        "CancelPolicy": {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "Numeric": "00"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "HotelRateCode": "RAC"
                },
                "SpecialOffers": {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "Ind": "false"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When a HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ is performed we can see that the total for the lowest rate is $429.14. Which is useful data as we can either display that on the initial search page or divide by the length of stay to determine a nightly average. The data returned by OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ is not very useful outside of determining availability. It would be nice if we could get some better pricing data out of the initial call.

Comment: That is how it is supposed to work. Hotel Avail API is used to search for hotels. If you want to get a list of rates you should use hotel property description. Further rate details can be displayed with hotel rate description API.

Comment: Its not very useful. If the lowest rate in a 2 day stay is 150, but the total stay is 350 since the 2nd night is 200. How is that useful to a consumer?

Comment: Is there a way to return multiple Hotel Property Descriptions in a single call or is that only for a single hotel?